# Memory leak in .NET when using the native crypto providers

Tags: c#, .net, memory, encryption

I have an application which needs to encrypt and decrypt strings.  Below is my decryption method:

```
  public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
  {
     try
     {
        //Decrypt:
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        Aes.Key = keyArray;
        Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        Aes.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = Aes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length);
        Aes.Clear();
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        return "FAILED:*" + cipherText + "*" + ex.Message;
     }
  }
```

However, this seems to leak.  As you can see, all of the variables are scoped locally so they should be released when this block is done.  As background, I'm calling this method sometimes almost nonstop.

In order to determine that there was I leak I inundate my server with many requests.  By carefully tracing each request through each path of code it takes, I determined this piece of code is the culprit. When commented in my memory use goes up drastically and linearly, when commented out (and simply returning the cipherText) memory use stays even.

Comment: Bad practice returning ex.Message. Let the exception propagate so you'll be sure to know that something bad happened.

Comment: do you get a leak if AesCryptoServiceProvider and the transform is wrapped in a using()?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes.  Everything is in logging/debug mode to try to pinpoint my problem.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your memory leak is in this method? What have you used to profile the memory leak? Have you tried to force the local variables in this method to be cleared before returning a value? What have you done to verify the problem? Its highly unlikely such an easy bug to catch would exist in AesCryptoServiceProvider() consider the breath of its usage and its age.  What I am hinting at is that this is unlikely the source of your leak.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I inundate my server with request, my carefully tracing each request through each path of code it takes, I determined this piece of code is the culprit.  When commented in my memory use goes up drastically, when commented out (and simply returning the cipherText) memory use stays even.

Comment: @kmarks2 - How do you handle the returned value.  I would suspect that before this method.  Because there really isn't anything it could be.  I also suggest a using statement.  So update your code, profile the updated code, and report back.  Please use proper memory profile software.

Comment: @Ramhound It goes through a processing method which takes certain action.  Currently I have that processing method turned off.  Right now my server is literelly receiving messages and either decrypting them or not.  After that everything else is turned off.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AesCryptoServiceProvider implements IDisposable. Try to use it in a `using`-block. Something like the below:

```
using(AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()){
        Aes.Key = keyArray; 
        Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
        Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 
        Aes.IV = IV; 
        using (ICryptoTransform cTransform = Aes.CreateDecryptor()){
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length); 
            Aes.Clear(); 
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length); 
        }
}
```

Comment: ICryptoTransform also implements IDisposable, so it would need to be wrapped as well

Comment: @PeskyGnat: Right, I have inserted this - Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Generally you should always dispose objects that implement IDisposable, such as AesCryptoServiceProvider. They usually use unmanaged resources, which aren't cleared by the Garbagecollector. So instead of

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
```

write

```
using (AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Dispose `Aes` in the **finally {}** block, so it would be disposed even if an exception happens.
2. Dispose `ICryptoTransform`. Since `ICryptoTransform` is `IDisposable` dispose it as well wrapping in the `using` statement

   ```
   public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
   {
      AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes;

      try
      {
         //Decrypt:
         byte[] keyArray;
         byte[] toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
         keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
         Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
         Aes.Key = keyArray;
         Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         Aes.IV = IV;

         using (ICryptoTransform cTransform = Aes.CreateDecryptor())
         {
           byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length);
           Aes.Clear();
           return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         return "FAILED:*" + cipherText + "*" + ex.Message;
      }
      finally
      {
         Aes.Dispose();
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As has been said elsewhere, objects that implement IDisposable do not get garbage collected immediately. If you do not call Dispose on a disposable object, either explicitly or by wrapping it in a using, that object will take longer to get garbage collected.

If you are using a try, you should consider declaring such variables outside of the try and implement the disposal in a finally block. Particularly with AesCryptoServiceProvider, where you want to make sure the Clear() method gets executed even when an error occurs, as a using will not do that for you.

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
   string decryptedMessage = null;
   AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = null;
   ICryptoTransform cTransform = null;

   try
   {
      //Decrypt:
      byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      byte[] toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

      AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
      Aes.Key = keyArray;
      Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      Aes.IV = IV;

      ICryptoTransform cTransform = Aes.CreateDecryptor();

      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length);
      decryptedMessage = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      decryptedMessage = "FAILED:*" + cipherText + "*" + ex.Message;
   }
   finally
   {
       if (cTransform != null)
       {
           cTransform.Dispose();
       }

       if (Aes != null)
       {
           Aes.Clear();
           Aes.Dispose();
       }
   }

   return decryptedMessage;
}
```

You should also consider letting the exception throw, by eliminating the catch block and keeping the finally, and handling it outside this method.

You could also return a bool for success/fail and pass your decrypted string using an out. That way you aren't potentially confusing your errors with your message content:

```
public bool string Decrypt(string cipherText, out string decryptedMessage)
{
   bool succeeded = false;
   decryptedMessage = null;
   AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = null;
   ICryptoTransform cTransform = null;

   try
   {
      //Decrypt:
      byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
      byte[] toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

      AesCryptoServiceProvider Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
      Aes.Key = keyArray;
      Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      Aes.IV = IV;

      ICryptoTransform cTransform = Aes.CreateDecryptor();

      byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length);
      decryptedMessage = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
      succeeded = true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      decryptedMessage = "FAILED:*" + cipherText + "*" + ex.Message;
   }
   finally
   {
       if (cTransform != null)
       {
           cTransForm.Dispose();
       }

       if (Aes != null)
       {
           Aes.Clear();
           Aes.Dispose();
       }
   }

   return succeeded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem which did not disappear after I applied all hints from the discussion. The problem appeared pointing directly to new AesCryptoServiceProvider() - it always crashed with out of memory in this method, and it did not happen if I commented this block out (like in the original post).

It turned out though that the problem was in the way how I organized the code. I applied hashing to the entire byte buffer in a single call to TransformFinalBlock, which was pretty big in my case - 500,000,000 bytes.

When I switched to using a combination of multiple TransformBlock followed by TransformFinalBlock everything worked well. Here is my final code (maybe you will find a more elegant way of writing the loop where TransformFinalBlock is called exactly one time at the last portion of the stream):

```
var bytes = new byte[4 * 1024];
int lastPortionSize;

using (var cryptographer = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider()) {
    var byteCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        lastPortionSize = sourceStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        byteCount += lastPortionSize;
        if (byteCount < totalSize) {
            cryptographer.TransformBlock(bytes, 0, lastPortionSize, bytes, 0);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    cryptographer.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, lastPortionSize);
    var hashBytes = cryptographer.Hash;
}
```